# Iterating over two lists and removing a value on condition in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, iteration

I have a list of time slots of an hour each and a list of slot bookings stored in Firestore for the same day. I now need to show availability of free slots to the user. So I am running the below code. It works fine if there is only one slot in a day, and it is booked. But it crashes with an index out of bounds error if there are more slots in a day and one of them is booked. Have spent multiple hours on this tried iterators and dont know why this is happening. Any solutions please?

Please note: i have looked at the below link, didnt work in my case:

[Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing objects in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

```
 val existingBookingsList: List<Booking> = it.toObjects(Booking::class.java)

            val newAvailableList: MutableList<String> = listOfAvailableSlots

            for (booking in existingBookingsList) {
                //change availability of the time slots
                val endTimeOfAppointment = createTime(booking.getstartTime()!!)
                //add duration to time stored in Minutes
                servDuration = booking.getduration()!!.toInt()
                if (servDuration == 0) {
                    durhrs = 0
                    durmins = 0
                } else if (servDuration < 60) {
                    durmins = servDuration
                    durhrs = 0
                } else {
                    val hrs: Int = servDuration / 60
                    val mins = servDuration - (hrs * 60)
                    durhrs = hrs
                    durmins = mins
                }
                endTimeOfAppointment.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, durhrs)
                endTimeOfAppointment.add(Calendar.MINUTE, durmins)
```

//Above is getting the endTime for each slot that has been booked for a particular date

//below is looping the end time over the slots that can be booked to identify and remove the overlap

//Error occurs on this line val hour = listOfAvailableSlots[j] - Index out of bounds index 2 and size is 1

```
                for (j in 0 until listOfAvailableSlots.size) {
                    val hour = listOfAvailableSlots[j]
                    val endTime = createTime(hour)
                    if (endTimeOfAppointment.compareTo(endTime) >= 0) {
                        newAvailableList.removeAt(j)
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several problems in the code.

At the line `val newAvailableList: MutableList<String> = listOfAvailableSlots` you are not initializing a new list containing the values of `listOfAvailableSlots`. You are assigning the pointer of `listOfAvailableSlots` to `newAvailableList` so every action you perform on `newAvailableList` is reflected to `listOfAvailableSlots`. The easiest way to copy a list to another variable is using .toMutableList(). It works even if the source list is already mutable. `val newAvailableList: MutableList<String> = listOfAvailableSlots.toMutableList()`

The code below can be modified

```
for (j in 0 until listOfAvailableSlots.size) {
    val hour = listOfAvailableSlots[j]
    val endTime = createTime(hour)
    if (endTimeOfAppointment.compareTo(endTime) >= 0) {
        newAvailableList.removeAt(j)
    }
}
```

to this

```
for(availableSlot in listOfAvailableSlot) {
    val endTime = createTime(availableSlot)
    if(endTimeOfAppointment.compareTo(endTime) >= 0) {    //consider to use greaterThan or lessThan
        newAvailableList.remove(availableSlot)
    }
}
```

which is safer than the previous.

In the same way you can use the filter function:

```
newAvailableList.filter { endTimeOfAppointment.compareTo(createTime(it) >= 0) }
```

Try to clean your code and let us know if you solved the problem

Comment: In programming in general, we always need to have into account this sort of stuff regarding memory and pointers. It really helps to understand a little further how memory works. That way you can spot these kind of errors (and some even worse) for yourself and it really pays off.